# How to replace volumes_from in docker-composer v3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to know the equivalent of the configuration below to suit version 3 of docker-composer.yml! volumes_from is no longer valid so am I supposed to skip the data volume and replace it with top level volumes ?

```
version: '2'
services:

  php:
    build: ./docker-files/php-fpm/.
    volumes_from:
      - data
    working_dir: /code
    links:
      - mysql

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    volumes_from:
      - data
    links:
      - php

  data:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default named volumes allow you to share data between containers. But it is some troubles with storing data in the same place on the host machine after restarting containers. But we can use [local-persist](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist) docker plugin for fix it.

For migration to version 3 you need

1) install [local-persist](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist) docker plugin (*if you want to store volumes data to the particular place on the host machine*)

2) modify `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:

  php:
    build: ./docker-files/php-fpm/.
    volumes:
      - data:/code
    working_dir: /code
    links:
      - mysql

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    volumes:
      - data:/code
    links:
      - php

  data:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - data:/code

# If you use local persist plugin
volumes:
  data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /path/on/host/machine/

# Or If you dont want using local persist plugin
volumes:
  data:
```

Also you can store volumes data to the host machine with this volumes section:

```
volumes:
  data:
    external: true #< it means store my data to the host machine
```

But you can't specify path for this volume on host machine

Comment: Ok, but the data: service has no function any longer? And is there any downsides by just share the host volume directly?

Like 

`volumes: .:/code`

Comment: you need data container only if this container encapsulate data inside himself. in this case you can simply backup this data, move container (with data) to another host. This is [data only container pattern](http://container42.com/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/).
But if you want use another approach: store data on the host machine then data container is unnecessary

Comment: installing third-party plugins for fundamental functionality (such us having a specific mountpoint on host) is unacceptable when you want to share your setup with other users. I am very disappointed by docker devs for leaving that basic functionality outside docker-compose version 3

Comment: `depends_on` can be used instead of `links`

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question. And your comment still doesn't address the concern about having a data only container. In this configuration, the service ``data: ...`` will never get used. (as of May 2018)

Comment: Without installing any plugins please.

Comment: any updates on dependency on third-party components?