# Docker compose external volume path

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Where is the mount point of an [external volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) located on a windows 10 host machine when using docker compose v3? e.g. The host path for mydata when the top-level volumes key is set as follows:

```
volumes:
  mydata:
    external: true
```

Comment: @FiberOptic as here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42244742/594323

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out that external volume is just a volume that has been created outside of Docker Compose and it is still located inside docker's vm:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx in my case.
```

For sharing data between my host and the containers I can define standard volumes inside the compose services and specify my preferred host directory there, or use [local persist plugin](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist)

("Create named local volumes that persist in the location(s) you want").

Answer (score 7):

Using external makes docker search for a folder named what you called it - in your case `mydata`.

If this folder doesn't exist there will be no mount and no error will be raised.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#external

You can also use the inspect to see the exact location:

```
Docker inspect -f "{{json. Mounts}}" container_name | jq.
```

https://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/

Comment: The docs (linked) says mydata is a volume name, not a file name, and external volumes does not have a path configuration key (to point to a target directory).

Comment: Where did you read this? 
And the inspect option was already suggested by Fiber Optic, I will try it.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. If the external volume doesn't exist, an error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the internal path used by Docker, try to inspect an existing one:

```
docker volume inspect my-vol.
```

It will show where the data is stored.

Comment: Did you inspect it?

Comment: I`m getting an error trying to create external volume (ERROR: Volume data declared as external, but could not be found). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479767/docker-compose-volume-declared-as-external-but-could-not-be-found

Comment: As said in the 2nd post, create an external volume before trying to "link" it.

Comment: Inspect gives me a guest path -  "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data" but I dont see the host windows path there

Comment: It works for me fine, with the data named volume:

docker volume inspect data

`[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-05-27T08:38:01Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data",
        "Name": "data",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]`

There is a /var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db, which should contain the further information... :-)