# volume with files in Dockerfile, available in other containers with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have one Dockerfile which more or less does:

```
VOLUME /files
RUN echo "foo" > /files/x
```

And then I have a docker-compose.yml which more or less is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  files:
    volumes:
      - files:/files
  other_service:
    volumes:
      - files:/files
    depends_on:
      - files
volumes:
  files:
```

The problem is that the /files gets overwritten by the docker-compose (and gets empty).
In the past (with docker-compose v2) I think that I used something like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  files:
  other_service:
    volumes_from:
      - files
    depends_on:
      - files
```

worked

How can I do it in version 3?

(Declaring a volume in the Dockerfile, putting some files inside this volume and then, have these files available in other containers (with docker-compose)

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244079/how-to-replace-volumes-from-in-docker-composer-v3